# How to filter values on maps and return results

Tags: filter, clojure, maps

I want to write a filter function for maps, That is going to filter the given value on all id name and surname props.

If possible I especially need one filter func code that is similar to my code. I would like to compare and understand my error. And then if possible can you share with me some other ideas and ways to do that? That would be nice for me and of course the community who going to need it in the future. :)

```
;this is my input map
(def my-map {1 {:id 1 :name "ali" :surname "veli"}
             2 {:id 2 :name "batu" :surname "can"}
             3 {:id 3 :name "bar" :surname "foo"}
             4 {:id 4 :name "zap" :surname "can"}
             }) 

;my expected result for "ba" ---> there are two "ba" value on name prop
{2 {:id 2 :name "batu" :surname "can"}
 3 {:id 3 :name "bar" :surname "foo"}}

;my expected result for "ca" ---> there are two "ca" value on surname prop
{2 {:id 2 :name "batu" :surname "can"}
 4 {:id 4 :name "zap" :surname "can"}}

;my expected result for "z" ---> there is just one "z" value on surname prop
{4 {:id 4 :name "zap" :surname "can"}}

;This is my search function ---> it is search just on surname at the moment(to find my ;error debugging :))

(defn filter-db-by-surname [?s db]
  (->> (for [lenght (range 1 (+ 1 (count my-map)))]
         (db lenght))                                           
       (filter
         (fn
           [{:keys [id name surname]} ]
           (let [i id
                 k name
                 v surname]
             (if (str/includes? (str/lower-case (str v)) (str/lower-case (str ?s)))
               (into [] {id (my-map i)})
               ())
             )))))


(filter-db-by-surname "ca" my-map
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(require '[clojure.string :as str])

(defn filter-map-by-str [data s & fields]
  (into (empty data)
        (filter (fn [[_k v]]
                  (some #(str/includes? (% v) s) fields)))
        data))

(def my-map {1 {:id 1 :name "ali" :surname "veli"}
             2 {:id 2 :name "batu" :surname "can"}
             3 {:id 3 :name "bar" :surname "foo"}
             4 {:id 4 :name "zap" :surname "can"}
             })

(filter-map-by-str my-map "z" :name :surname)
=> {4 {:id 4, :name "zap", :surname "can"}}
```

Comment: Great help thank you so much! Why my filter attempt does not work? If possible can you take a look, please?  What is my error...

Comment: All sorts of things, but the main are: `filter` filters based on the truth-y value of the predicate, the value itself is then discarded; and the way you call `filter` never turns the results back into a map. BTW, just in case you don't know about it - feel free to drop by the #beginners channel of the Clojurians Slack. Kind people there will be able to walk you through any issues you might have.

Answer (score 2):

Your function returns all entries because the function used in `filter` always returns a truthy value- a vector with a map entry or an empty list. It never returns `false` or `nil`, so nothing is filtered away.

Some other notes about your code:

- Your parentheses are strangely formatted. You should use a proper editor, which handles it for you.
- `(+ 1 ...)` is [`inc`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/inc) and that whole `for` loop can be replaced with [`vals`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/vals) (but I don't understand why would you want to remove your keys, when you need them at the end).
- I don't see any reason to introduce three additional variables with let, especially when they are just your old variables, but with more cryptic names.
- Why do you call `(str v)` or `(str ?s)`, when `v` and `?s` are already strings?
- `filter` return sequence- you still need to convert this result into hash-map.

Your `filter-db-by-surname`, simplified. Note that this solution uses [transducers](https://clojure.org/reference/transducers):

```
(defn filter-db-by-surname [substring db]
  (into {}
        (filter (fn [[_ {:keys [surname]}]]
                  (str/includes? (str/lower-case surname)
                                 (str/lower-case substring))))
        db))
```

You can also solve this with [`reduce-kv`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reduce-kv):

```
(defn filter-db-by-surname [substring db]
  (reduce-kv (fn [m k {:keys [surname] :as v}]
               (if (str/includes? (str/lower-case surname)
                                  (str/lower-case substring))
                 (assoc m k v)
                 m))
             {} db))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that is a great effort that you put to explain to me. I guess all Clojurians are extremely helpful and kind people. Wish you a great day!